# Dynamic react toggle button for multiple elements

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, react-hooks, boolean, toggle

I need to toggle multiple blocks with true/false in react state, but true and false works for all blocks at the same time.

```
import { useState } from "react";
...
const [toggleThisElement, setToggleThisElement] = useState(false);
...

{
    data.map((d, id) => {
        return (
            <div className="single-history" key={id}>
                <div className="h-head">
                    click this div for toggle h-info block
                </div>

                <div className="h-info">toggling block</div>
            </div>
        )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, all your toggle items share the same state. To avoid that create a separate component for toggling logic called `ToggleItem` as below.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const ToggleItem = ({ discription, id }) => {
  const [toggleThisElement, setToggleThisElement] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="single-history" key={id}>
      <button
        className="h-head"
        onClick={() => setToggleThisElement((prev) => !prev)}
      >
        click this btn for toggle h-info block {id}
      </button>

      {toggleThisElement && <div className="h-info">{discription}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const data = ["first", "second", "third"];

  return (
    <>
      {data.map((d, id) => {
        return <ToggleItem id={id} discription={d} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit nifty-snow-z4umy]

Comment: Thanks! Everything is working. So this is the only way to create dynamic toggles ? I mean I've tried filter method as well to compare which id of block I've clicked but that doesn't worked for me

Comment: If you use a state for a selected item then only one item will be able to toggle at a time. This is the normal way to organizing logic in components.